# Minimal Drop down menu trigger individual child

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to produce a simple drop down menu, with minimal JS and CSS.

It works perfectly but triggers all child elements at once rather than the element hovered over.

```
<nav id="product-index">
        <ul class="product-list">
            <li class="prod-trig">Bikes</li>
                <li><ul class="product-sub">
                <p>Bike product sub</p>
                </ul></li>

            <li class="prod-trig">Parts &amp; Tools</li>
                <li><ul class="product-sub">
                <p>Bike product sub</p>
                </ul></li>

            <li class="prod-trig">Clothes &amp; Shoes</li>
                <li><ul class="product-sub">
                <p>Bike product sub</p>
                </ul></li>

            <li class="prod-trig">Protection</li>
                <li><ul class="product-sub">
                <p>Bike product sub</p>
                </ul></li>

            <li class="prod-trig">More</li>
                <li><ul class="product-sub">
                <p>Bike product sub</p>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.prod-trig').hover(function() {
        $('.product-sub').stop().slideDown(400);
    }, function() {
        $('.product-sub').stop().slideUp(400);
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/npLwX/55/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('.prod-trig').hover(function() {
    $(this).next().find('.product-sub').stop().slideDown(400);
}, function() {
    $(this).next().find('.product-sub').stop().slideUp(400);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/npLwX/62/)**

You need to target the specific element rather than the entire class.

Comment: Works perfectly, is that because its not actually a child of prod-trig

Comment: Right, product-sub isn't a child of prod-trig; it's a child of the sibling of prod-trig.